# Saving data once (to be able to load to images to server) then updating the same instance after some changes

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm saving the data from the post request a first time because I need the images to be uploaded to the server like the "upload_image" function suggests.
At the same time I have a couple of fields that are null and need to have some values via some external functions.
And then I need to save the whole object in the database.

The problem that I'm facing is that it saves the data twice in the database.
And the first saved object has all attributes null except for passengerPhoto, passengerPassport and agent. ( No errors shown btw)

Any ideas, please? 
Thanks a lot!

```py
#VIEW
class IdentityCheckView(CreateAPIView, generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = IdentityCheckSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        qs = IdentityCheck.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=query)
        return qs

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        if(serializer.is_valid()):
            res = self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
            image = FaceRecognition.imageMatch(res.data['passengerPhoto'], res.data['passengerPassport'])
            wanted = WantedPro.criminalMatch(res.data['passengerPhoto'])

            passport_json = OCR.passportMatch(res.data['passengerPassport'])
            image_json = json.loads(image)


            firstName      = passport_json['names']
            lastName       = passport_json['surname']
            nationality    = passport_json['country']
            birthDate      = passport_json['date_of_birth']
            gender         = passport_json['sex']
            ableToBoard    = bool(wanted) & bool(image_json['match']) & bool(passport_json['valid_expiration_date'])


            serializer.update(
                                id=res.data['id'],
                                firstName=firstName,
                                lastName=lastName,
                                nationality=nationality,
                                birthDate=birthDate,
                                gender=gender,
                                ableToBoard=ableToBoard)



        return Response({"image": image_json, "passport": passport_json, "wanted": wanted}, status=200)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        res = serializer.save(agent=self.request.user)



#SERIALIZER
class IdentityCheckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = IdentityCheck
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['agent', 'id']


#MODEL
def upload_image(instance, filename):
    return "media/check/{agent}/{date}/{filename}".format(agent=instance.agent,date=datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'), filename=filename)


class IdentityCheckQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    pass

class IdentityCheckManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return IdentityCheckQuerySet(self.model,using=self._db)

class IdentityCheck(models.Model):
    agent               = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    passengerPhoto      = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image, null=False, blank=False)
    passengerPassport   = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image, null=False, blank=False)
    lastName            = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    firstName           = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    birthDate           = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    nationality         = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    gender              = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    ableToBoard         = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=False)
    timestamp           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = IdentityCheckManager()
```

Comment: you're not saying what's the exact problem you're facing. what's not working? what's the error?

Comment: Oh that's right sorry I'll edit it

Comment: I don't understand how `serializer.update()` can work, as it should take only two arguments, `instance` and `validated_data`. But you're overcomplicating things by first doing `res = self.create(...)`. You should just build all your variables using `serializer.validated_data` (instead of `res.data`) and then do `serializer.save(firstName=..., ..., agent=self.request.user)` which will make the first and only call to the db to create the object.

Comment: Yeah I did that at first, but serializer.validated_data gives me the image path as specified on my computer, which is something I don't want to save in the database. And I need to save the image uri that refers to the server (exple: "localhost:8000/media/...img.jpg").

Comment: no, you're wrong. you have an ImageField, you don't need to worry about what is exactly saved there, but what is saved needs to be the os.path to the image (in a way django can find the file on the file system), not a URL. The url can be obtained once the model is saved from `instance.passengerPhoto.url`.

Comment: but I see what you're trying to say: you need a way to pass the uploaded image to `FaceRecognition`. what is the expected input for `FaceRecognition.imageMatch()` function? A `File` object? Or a file path?

Comment: Yeah I see now! Actually a url is passed to the imageMatch() function.
Like so "localhost:8000/media/check/agent_name/date/filename"